How can I have a local Array in each struct?
My code uses a ref struct to parse some data from a file. I took some inspiration from the Utf8JsonReader that uses the same approach. It's a struct that can be duplicated to read in different scenarios. You can make a copy of that struct and read on. Then you can use the copy and continue reading from the state on that was current when the copy was made. This allows you to read ahead, looking for something to come, and then continue in the normal flow.
That works pretty nicely, but there's a catch. To track nesting state, I need some kind of array or collection. I added an array to my struct to store data to it.
But that array will always be the same instance. When I make a copy of the reader, and then continue reading (which changes the contents of the array), the previous copy will see the same changes in the array. That must not happen.
How can I change the following code so that each struct instance has their own copy of the array, and so that the array is also copied/cloned when the struct is copied?
I'd also accept a stackalloc array[] field in my Reader to make the array a part of the structure, but that doesn't seem to exist. It's always referring to a separate array on the heap.
I've also tried to wrap the array in a separate struct and use wrapper methods but that didn't change anything. Something is still missing.
public ref struct Reader
{
    private struct LevelInfo
    {
        private ushort indentation;

        public int Indentation
        {
            readonly get
            {
                return indentation;
            }
            set
            {
                ArgumentOutOfRangeException.ThrowIfLessThan(value, 0);
                ArgumentOutOfRangeException.ThrowIfGreaterThan(value, 0b00111111_11111111);
                indentation = (ushort)value;
            }
        }
    }

    private LevelInfo[] levels;

    // example usage:
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        levels[0].Indentation = 1;
    }
}

Note: This example is heavily simplified. The LevelInfo struct has more fields and methods and the array is initialised in the Reader constructor to a certain predefined length.

Try using Clone which will make a copy rather than using copy which often in c# just creates a new pointer to the original data.

The point of the ref struct is that it can be copied and will always be a clone.

@ygoe That's not the point of a ref struct. Regardless, the levels member is a reference type. When you "copy" a Reader object, you copy the reference to the same LevelInfo[] array. You could write a copy constructor for Reader.

Does the array have a fixed size? If it does, perhaps you can use a fixed size buffer or inline array. That said, I agree with Jonathan Dodds that you are misusing ref structs. This copy behaviour that you are describing is available on all value types.
